# What is this flower called?

Tags: identification, flowers, plant-care

If you can identify if, can it safely live inside ?[image]

Comment: benn is right, looks like azalea.
I haven't seen it inside.

Answer (score 3):

You seem to have an *Azalea*, it is related to *Rhododendron*. Azalea can be kept indoors, but only under proper conditions. It likes a lot of indirect sun light, so try not to keep it in full sun light. Also put the plant in a pot with proper drainage, too wet or too dry soil can kill the plant. Be careful with fertilizer, too much can also be harmful. Here is some more detailed info about [*Azalea*](https://www.gardeningknowhow.com/ornamental/shrubs/azalea/azaleas-noteworthy-shrubs-for-any-garden.htm).